# Multi users for Excel VBA userform

Tags: excel, ms-access, userform

I have made my connection to a Access DB to allow multi entries. It now takes a range and adds it to a table. All perfect. But now I want to have multiple users using the Excel userform to populate Access DB.

Is this possible or do I have to rewrite my whole userform?

Answer (score 1):

Enable `events = True`

This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple people use Excel requires you to 'share' the workbook.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61

This is NOT a good idea.  Given enough time, Excel will crash, and/or get corrupted, and you'll lose all your data.  Just split your Access DB and share the front end with the users.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
Excel uses the form only for a second to link it to acces. I already have it working. Opening as READ ONLY. User opens a copy, gets the user interface with the worksheet layout and then queries it to acces DB. Stress testing soon.